# Is Geralt's attack speed slower with a heavier weapon?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Does the weight of the sword affect Geralt's attack speed?

My currently equipped sword is about 2.5 Witcher Units of Measurement

Patch 1.07

*I have not played in about 5 days and I do not remember if this was happening in 1.06*

---

Background:

I was playing yesterday and noticed that it is taking Geralt much longer to actually execute a swinging motion with his sword and thus leaving him open to attacks for a much longer duration of time.

This has caused several miscalculations during battle on my part and I have been dying more frequently.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I have noticed the attacking animation is different per weapon TYPE. I'm not sure about the same weapon type having a different weight. I'll have to check this out and get back to you.

Comment: @ChaseC I look forward to your findings!

Comment: +1 for 'Witcher Units of Measurement." Also I think it's a worthwhile question that deserves an answer.

Comment: @Dallium Haha, thanks! I would test this theory out on my own and provide an answer but I haven't had any time to play the game since I posted this question :(

Answer (score 1):

The speed of the attacks is done completely through weapon class. It has nothing to do with the weapons themselves. Similar to league of legends however, different materials have different "animation speed" in which they finish their attacks. So it appears to finish the attack faster, however it is the exact same speed.

Example..  "-" is wait time., "+" is the attack

`--+--+--` is the same as

`-+---+--`

It just appears faster because the animation is faster.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "different material" refers to? I am aware of silver vs normal sword.

Answer (score -3):

no your attacks are slower
cause u need to change it in keybinds, its opposite now of what its written
its a bug

now faster is right click and slower harder attacks are left click
just change this 2 and you should be fine

Comment: This is not my experience. Are you sure that you (or someone else) have not rebound your keys?

Comment: **⊙_ʘ** I am aware of the differences between a fast and strong attack. My fast attack feels slower than it used to. I am using an XBox 360 controller and read nothing about inverted key bindings in their **[changelog](http://thewitcher.com/news/view/1081)**